# Existence of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Show that if $R$ has an identity and $A$ is a $R$-module, then there are submodules $B$ and $C$ of $A$ such that $B$ is unitary, $RC = 0$ and $A = B ⊕ C.$

Give my hint, I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that a unitary $R$-module $A$ is precisely one where $1a=a$ for all $a\in A$?

If $A$ is not unitary, try $B:=\{b\in A : 1b=b\}$ and $C:=\{c\in A : 1c=0\}$. I'll leave it to you to check that $B,C$ are submodules, $RC=0$, $B$ is unitary, and $B\cap C=0$.

To see that $A=B+C$, I'll give you a hint: $a=1a+(a-1a)$.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I will check everything in a moment. I don't know answer to your question, it is not written in my document. My first question: what is $RC=0$ because after you using notation $B∩C=0$? I thought $RC=R∩C=\emptyset$ Second question: Why do we have to check if $B∩C=0$? Third question: you assumed $A$ is not unitary, there is one case left, when $A$ is not unitary?

Comment: $RC=\{rc: c\in C\}$. In fact $R\cap C$ does not make sense because $R$ is not a subset of $A$. For $B\cap C=0$, that's the definition of a direct sum: $A=B\oplus C$ if and only if $A=B+C$ and $B\cap C=0$. Lastly: if $A$ is already unitary then there is nothing to prove, since $C=0$ and $B=A$.